# How do I install Windows and Ubuntu on different SSDs?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, ssd

I have 2 SSDs. I have already installed Ubuntu in one, and it works pretty well. Now I want to install Windows on the other SSD that I have, in fact, I installed it, but it doesn't come up. I thought by holding the <kbd>F12</kbd> and selecting which partition to come up in the BIOS I could select which OS to boot. But seems like it is not working.

What should I do? Where did I go wrong ?

Isn't it possible to install Linux in one SSD and Windows in the other What can I do to be able to install Windows in one and linux in the other?

When I choose the hard drive in which Windows is installed, I get

```
Please insert a bootable media and try again  .
```

Logically it must work but why it isn't working?

Comment: Helping installing windows is not for this forum. That being said, have you tried to reinstall windows?

Comment: @ldias its not about windows , its about dual booting . how can i have linux `ubuntu` and windows both , each one installed in a different `HDD`

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: You need to be sure to install both systems in same boot mode. And any system since 2012 uses UEFI.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives or drives that are unallocated. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs, so only boot in UEFI mode. What brand/model system? Best to disconnect one drive or in UEFI change one to disabled temporarily.